# Do I need to backup the files in /opt directory when upgrading Solaris 11 to Solaris 11.3?

Tags: solaris, upgrade

Do I need to backup the files in `/opt` directory when upgrading Solaris 11 to Solaris 11.3? The upgrade can be done by `pkg update --accept` like it is described [here](http://www.unixarena.com/2014/08/upgrade-oracle-solaris-11-1-oracle-solaris-11-2.html).

Comment: Just back up everything, better safe than sorry.

Comment: Yes, I think so :) And see what happens after upgrade.

Comment: Note that going from 11.0 to 11.3 is not an upgrade but a (less intrusive) update. There is no specific need to backup the /opt directory, at least not anymore than any other directory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a best practice always do a full backup before an OS upgrade.
Although with Solaris 11 it is pretty straightforward and so far I have not experience issues, we never know.

Please remember that when you update your Solaris 11.x it creates a new boot environment; at any given time, you can activate your previous boot environment and return to the previous OS version.

```
beadm active <be_name>
```

Please ensure that you have enough disk space and remember to destroy the previous boot environment once you are sure that the new version did/is not causing any issues.

If you wish to see the changes to the system before patching, you can also do:

```
pkg update -nv --accept 2>&1 |tee pkg_update.log
```

This will run a dry-run verbose update and log it to the file. You can then check the file for changes on the packages and script to use `pkg contents`  and filter by `/opt`, it will be a bit of overkill but doable.

Comment: How can I destroy the previous boot environment after upgrade?

Comment: Have you check the man page for beadm? beadm destroy <old_be_name>

Comment: Yes, I've destroyed old Solaris boot environments, and the files in `/opt` directory were untouched. Super, thanks for help :)